# associate nulls as false on filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tbl` that has a column `IsLib` that is bit but also accepts nulls and it has to be this way. I have a query that brings in a parameter `@bitIsLib` that is true or false and I need to filter `tbl` based on this. I cant do this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE IsLib = @bitIsLib
```

because I need to treat nulls as false and they will be excluded from this filter. How can I write it so if `@bitIsLib` is true then it includes true values, and if `@bitIsLib` is false then it includes false **and** null values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ISNULL(IsLib, 0) = @bitIsLib
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `IsLib` column with `IS NULL` condition in `where` clause when `@bitIsLib = 0`

Here is one way

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE IsLib = @bitIsLib 
   or (@bitIsLib = 0 and IsLib is null)
```